# unable to access a spring Rest web service deploy on tomcat through angular JS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, tomcat

Hello everyone I've been looking through posts related to this problem and I didn't find a solution to my problem. Actually  I have a spring RestController that perform cetain task (backend) I would like to use use those services through an angularJs app but I have the folowing error message

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8084/BackendHibernateJPA/abonnes. Origin http://localhost:8383 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (14:19:15:639 | error, javascript)
  at app/index.html"
```

when I run the Spring Rest project I can find the expected result on my browser. I can also have the result through rest client like "Chrome Rest client", but I can't cosume the services with angularJS

here is my RestController

```
import com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.service.IAbonneService;
import com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.entities.Abonne;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:8383"}, methods = {RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT}, allowedHeaders = "true")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abonnes")
public class AbonneController {

    @Autowired
    private IAbonneService iAbonneService; //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work

    //-------------------Retrieve All Abonne--------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Abonne>> findAllAbonnes() throws Exception {
        List<Abonne> listAbonnes = iAbonneService.findAll();
        if (listAbonnes.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(listAbonnes, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/some/{idDomicile}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Abonne>> findSomeAbonnes(@PathVariable("idDomicile") long idDomicile) throws Exception {
        List<Abonne> listAbonnes = iAbonneService.findSomeAbonne(idDomicile);
        if (listAbonnes.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(listAbonnes, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //-------------------Retrieve Single Abonne--------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Abonne> findAbonneById(@PathVariable("id") long id) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
        Abonne user = iAbonneService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Abonne with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    //-------------------Create an Abonne--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createAbonne(@RequestBody Abonne abonne, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws Exception {
        iAbonneService.create(abonne);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/abonne/{id}").buildAndExpand(abonne.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    //------------------- Update a Abonne --------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Abonne> updateAbonne(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Abonne abonne) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Updating Abonne " + id);
        Abonne currentAbonne = iAbonneService.findById(id);
        if (currentAbonne == null) {
            System.out.println("Abonne with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        currentAbonne.setNomAbonne(abonne.getNomAbonne());
        currentAbonne.setTel(abonne.getTel());
        iAbonneService.update(currentAbonne);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(currentAbonne, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //------------------- Delete a Abonne --------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Abonne> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);
        Abonne abonne = iAbonneService.findById(id);
        if (abonne == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to delete. Abonne with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        iAbonneService.delete(abonne);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

here is my servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="iAbonneDao" class="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.daoImpl.AbonneDaoImpl"/> 
    <bean id="iAbonneService" class="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.serviceImpl.AbonneServiceImpl"/>

    <!-- couche de persistance JPA -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">            
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">   
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:bd.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- la source de donnéees DBCP -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${bd.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${bd.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${bd.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${bd.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- le gestionnaire de transactions -->

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


    <!-- traduction des exceptions -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <!-- annotations de persistance -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!--    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>-->

</beans>
```

I've even added this in my web.xml

```
<!--     ================== Built In Filter Definitions ===================== -->   

<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- ==================== Built In Filter Mappings ====================== -->
```

and finaly, here is my angular service

```
'use strict';

var services = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);
services.factory('abonneFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8084/BackendHibernateJPA/abonnes/', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    });
});
services.factory('abonneFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8084/BackendHibernateJPA/abonnes/:id', {}, {
        show: {method: 'GET'},
        update: {method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}},
        delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By the error message this seems to be a **CORS** issue 
*Access-Control-Allow-Origin*. This happens when a **site A** tries to fetch content from **site B**. You should implements **CORS** in your application adding this headers in backend:

```
public static final HttpHeaders HTTP_HEADERS = new HttpHeaders();
static{
    HTTP_HEADERS.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    HTTP_HEADERS.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    HTTP_HEADERS.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

And add these headers to the service response, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/{idDomicile}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Abonne>> findSomeAbonnes(@PathVariable("idDomicile") long idDomicile) throws Exception {
    List<Abonne> listAbonnes = iAbonneService.findSomeAbonne(idDomicile);
    if (listAbonnes.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HTTP_HEADERS).body(listAbonnes);
}
```

Another option is use an extension in your browser

**For chrome:**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

**For firefox**
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/

Comment: from spring documentation, I found that " @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:8383"}, methods = {RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT}, allowedHeaders = "true")" on my controller was what I had to do have noticed this on my controller?

Comment: Yes, that will be another option, you can use the anotation `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8383")` on yours methods

Comment: It is what I did on the class controller but it doen't work I'm going to try your suggestion then I keep you posted

Comment: The example I posted is easier, but if you want to use the annotation`@CrossOrigin...` you need override `addCorsMappings` method from **org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer**. check this example https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem I found this on Spring web site

> You might need to force your browser to reload the static resources
>   after you change them. In Chrome (and Firefox with a plugin) you can
>   use "developer tools" (F12), and that might be enough. Or you might
>   have to use CTRL+F5.

I dont really understand why but it worked for me. So @CrossOrigin is enough to configure Cross-origin resource sharing